How would an empiricist view the question of God and soul?
How would an empiricist view the question of God and soul? How would he attempt to prove it or disprove it using experience and empirical evidence? Does an empiricist have to believe in a material or immaterial God or soul or none of them? How can he justify his belief either way?

Regarding God: How can a belief in God be reconciled with modern science?, Can belief in God be grounded in (and justified by) personal experience rather than philosophical argumentation?

Related: Are some religious claims subject to empirical testing?

I suspect that you're thinking of something like operationalism, not empiricism, since I doubt that you'd accept going to your nearest mosque and fasting and chanting the Shahada for days until you have a numinous sensory experience as an example of a solution, even though it is quite empirical. Is that correct?

This question is similar to: Can belief in God be grounded in (and justified by) personal experience rather than philosophical argumentation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"... the question of God and soul". What is the question?

There are far too many upvotes on the answer about the pseudoscientific mumbo jumbo that is "parapsychology" (and the other one). Using a name that references an existing scientific field (psychology) helps nonsense sound more legitimate. And of course we need some accusation of bias to explain why 99.9% of the scientific community rejects that, as the nonsense that it is.

Another duplicate / related question: Can science or history be used to examine religions claims despite it being a naturalist enterprise that denies the existence of the supernatural?

On the question of souls, that (typically) posits that consciousness exists distinctly from the brain. The closest scientific question may be "there isn't a correlation between consciousness and brain", and that's something we've thoroughly disproven, by showing an extremely strong correlation in every way at every point. Proponents of souls/dualism tend to agree there is such a correlation, but that the consciousness (in some part) still exists outside the brain. But there's no way to test or justify that claim, particularly not empirically (unless they can find where the correlation fails).

Views widely differ on this. Immanuel Kant who first laid the epistemological foundations of science ruled out any empirical or rational science of God and soul. With vitalism seen discredited with advances in biology, most scientists came to just assume that they don't actually need the concept of soul or God to explain the formerly inexplicable natural phenomena, so these subjects were just removed from science.
However some scientists believed religious experience (in contrast to theologies) could be a valid subject of empirical investigation.
Prominent among these was the 19th century foundational psychologist, William James who took an interest in empirical study of experiences with religious character, such as mystical experiences.
There were other scientist and philosophers whose curiosity about claims of "supernatural" or "psychic" phenomena was prompted by the spiritualist movement. These actually thought phenomena of interest to spiritualists could and should be studied by empirical methods of modern science. They hoped to find out whether these anomalous phenomena could be verified as proof of soul or God, or explained away as sham or illusion.
A neglected genius in this tradition that James himself highly admired, was F. W. H. Myers, the most dedicated and productive parapsychologist at Society for Psychical Research. Myers believed in expanding the scope of empirical psychology to include study of various anomalous experiences such as mediumship as probable windows to higher realities espoused by religions. He did produce a very rich work, coming up with a theory of human psyche that he thought could take into account the best available evidence for paranormal and psi phenomena which he dutifully catalogued and analyzed in his work Human Personality.
Sadly however these pioneering approach and work were neglected and pushed aside by the rise of logical positivism and behavioral psychology which extremely narrowed the subject matter of psychology, coupled with a prior materialistic conviction which just assumed a priori impossibility of paranormal realities.
Myer's approach and theory have been recently taken up by neuroscientist parapsychologists at UVA DOPS who believe sufficient good quality evidence from empirical study of various categories of parapsychological phenomena have been obtained over the intervening century to corroborate Myer's theory of human psyche. Myer's theory postulates a kind of transcendental higher source in the depth of both the world and human psyche which makes these extraordinary psychic phenomena possible. DOPS scientists have put together a massive and extremely rich work to show just that and they propose a dualist filter theory of mind as the best theory to account for both the physiological and transcendental bases of these experiences. Irreducible Mind is followed by two other sequels.

Recently they have also founded a lab for neuroscientific study of the neural conditions conducive to these extraordinary phenomena even though they obviously don't believe in neuroscientific reduction of them. You can also watch some of their presentations at their Youtube channel

Re. Kant Not so fast

@Rushi That might be a true interpretation but Kant unfortunately mostly made a disservice by arguing against rational psychology causing widespread alienation from the field. Not saying the discipline was flawless but progress must've been allowed.

The studies of God and Soul-related questions became a subject of ideology in science. One hint of the interest in studying these phenomena can put a cross on someone's scientific career. But there is hope out there. With Simulation Hypothesis slowly moving into the mainstream, studies of the supernatural could become normal empirical research, circumventing any ideological prejudice.

@ScottRowe - We are moving away from dualism: science or religion. Multiple layers of reality don't require religion anymore.

Carl Sagan's enthusiasm for the universe notwithstanding.

Rather barriers in those brains. Here they know, here they believe, but an in-between, impenetrable wall.
